# How to Generate the ID of a Random Toggle Button, Then SetChecked(True) That Specific Toggle Button

Tags: android, random, togglebutton, android-identifiers

I have two ToggleButtons and I want to be able to randomly select the id of one of those buttons, and set check that button to true. I tried This but is does not work as setChecked is not available for an Int or String. Any help would be much Appreciated.

```
int[] buttonIds = new int[] {R.id.player1Button, R.id.player2Button};
Random rand = new Random();
int num = rand.nextInt(buttonIds.length);
int buttonId = buttonIds[num];
findViewById(buttonId).toString();
String randomButton = getString(buttonId);
randomButton.setChecked(true); /// THIS LINE OF CODE WILL NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line instead

```
((ToggleButton)findViewById(buttonId)).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the id of the the remaining button in the array so i can setCheck it to false. Sometimes both Togglebuttons can be checked as one is already true on startup.

Comment: For (int i=0;i <buttonIds.length;i++){((ToggleButton)findViewById(buttonIds[i])).setChecked(false);} ((ToggleButton)findViewById(buttonId)).setChecked(true);

Comment: Thank you very Much. Worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a little confused at the end. Your code to pick a random `id` is fine.  But a `ToggleButton` is a class.  It is not a `String`.  If you convert it into a `String` via `toString()`, it will not have any of the `toggleButton` functions. Instead you want to `findViewById` to get the id, cast it to a `ToggleButton` and call `setChecked` on that `ToggleButton`.

Comment: Thank you friend I have managed to get it to work by doing like you said. I changed the last three line to         this : `findViewById(buttonId);`
 `ToggleButton randomButton = (ToggleButton)     findViewById(buttonId);`
`randomButton.setChecked(true);`

Comment: However as one of the ToggleButtons are already checked on startup, sometimes both togglebuttons can end up being checked.  Is there a way of getting the id of the the remaining button in the array so i can setCheck it to false at the same time

Comment: There's only 2 ids-  the random index you pick is either 0 or 1.  The other of those 2 values is the other button's index.